# How can I delay the visibility of my dialog box until tinyMCE has opened?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    open: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(this).data('action') == "Editing") {
            tinyMCE.init(window.tinyMCEOptions);
        }
        else {
            tinyMCE.init(window.tinyMCEReadOnly);
        }
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').
            find('button:contains("Submit")').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-plus'} });
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').
            find('button:contains("Cancel")').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-cancel'} });
        $(":input[type='checkbox']").wijcheckbox();
        $("#dialog_type").wijdropdown();
        $("#dialog_select").wijdropdown();
        $(":input[type='text'],:input[type='password'],textarea").not(".native").wijtextbox();
    }
```

This works BUT the screen first opens and shows a text box for a few seconds before tinyMCE appears to hide the text box. Is there some way I could delay opening of the dialog or visibility until tinyMCE has completed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the event `onPostRender`?

You can read about it here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onPostRender

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, with the dialog initially hidden, you need something like this:

```
// Adapted from http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onInit
// Adds an observer to the onInit event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
          //here, initialise then show the dialog
      });
   }
});
```

In practice, it appears that you need to add the whole setup callback to `window.tinyMCEOptions` and `window.tinyMCEReadOnly`, or maybe just add the ed.onInit callback to your setup callback if it already exists.